# editor.remove() in sharedpreferences not removing the key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have experienced a strange behavior that does not make any sense to me.

I have managed to save a value of temperature in sharedpreferences in a Java Class that is not an activity by doing this:

The method getContextOfApplication() is the one I am using in my Java.Class where i am putting the value of a temperature in a String and storing it in sharedpreferences as "temperature".

This method is declared in my MainActivity like this:

```
public static Context contextOfApplication;


public static Context getContextOfApplication() {
    return contextOfApplication;
}
```

This method getContextOfApplication(); is the used in all assosiacions with sharedpreferences, in Mainactivity and in my Java.Class

```
        tempParsed = Jobject.get(("temp")) + "";

        SharedPreferences tempSettings = getSharedPreferences(getContextOfApplication());
        SharedPreferences.Editor tempEdit = tempSettings.edit();
        tempEdit.putString("temperature",  tempParsed);
        tempEdit.apply();
```

And later I recieve this value of the key "temperature" in my MainActivity like this:

```
     SharedPreferences fetchSettings = 
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContextOfApplication());

     String Temp = fetchSettings.getString("temperature", "");
```

And I can use the stored temperaure with the String Temp.

So far so good.

Later on in my code I wanted to delete this string in that is saved in sharedpreferences with the key "temperature".

Easy I thought...

First I called this code when I wanted to delete the value / values

```
SharedPreferences fetchSettings = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContextOfApplication());

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = fetchSettings.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
```

But this code deletes ALL information that is stored, so I obvously didn't want that.

That's why I tried to change this line:

```
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
```

To this:

```
    editor.remove("temperature")
    editor.apply();
```

But this didn't work!!

Now you are probably wondering "Are you sure that is what your key is named?"

I added this code to read all entries that were stored in the defaultsharedpreferences:

```
 Map<String, ?> allEntries = fetchSettings.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("mapvalues ", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
    }
```

AND THE LOG SHOWS "temperature:" as the key....

**Why is editor.clear(); working but editor.remove("key") is not?**

Comment: did you used `editor.apply();` after `editor.remove("temperature")` ?

Comment: Yes I did, it worked with editor.clear(); so I had to.
I am wondering if the problem can be that when i Put The string i use "getSharedPreferences" but when I want to read and delete i call getDefaultSharedPreferences... Still the behavior of editor.remove is strange.

Comment: Yes, that is likely the problem. Those will use different preferences files.

Comment: `getSharedPreferences(getContextOfApplication())` is this your defined method ?

Comment: But how does that explain that editor.clear(); is working and editor.remove("key") is not ???

Comment: It's not really clear from your question exactly which method you're using where, and when. In any case, unless you need multiple, separate preferences, the default is sufficient. If you change your code to use that everywhere, you should clear your app's data after doing that, before testing again.

Comment: to avoid such "maybe" mistakes for your `temperature` key, always use static constants like `public static final KEY_TEMP = "temperature";` and use it like `editor.remove(KEY_TEMP)`. This way nobody will ask if you got a typo in your string

Comment: Mike M. You are right, please read my whole question again with updated information.

Comment: Could you post your method `getSharedPreferences(Context)` code. I think you are using a `name` for preference file  here for  and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` will use a fixed name .

Comment: This is just getting more weird... When i remove the key "temperature" in my code, it is working now, but I wanted it to be called when the user is turning off the GPS so i put it under the onProviderDisabled();

Comment: What happens if we try to remove a key that is not present in shared preference ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) you need to call commit for the changes to happen:

```
editor.remove("temperature").commit();
```

Comment: Updated my post, I did use editor.apply for the changes to take effect.

Comment: apply() does not modify the preferences file imediately, it is an async call. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: This is usually not the answer. It's almost never necessary to use commit() over apply()

Comment: really? I've aways favoured commit() over apply() due to problems I've had with the latter :/

Comment: What happens if we try to remove a key that is not present in shared preference ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
You can try this code for ***remove*** single preference:

```
Prefs.remove("my_custom_key");
```

Don't forget to import library:

```
import com.pixplicity.easyprefs.library.Prefs;
```

This code worked for me Beautifully.

Comment: What happens if we try to remove a key that is not present in shared preference ?